# Передача данных между устройствами Android

Tags: android, phonegap, cordova

Я пишу приложение для Android на Cordova. Мне нужно связать 2 устройства и передавать данные. Данные - это просто пару чисел. То есть, когда на 1 устройстве что то происходит, на второй должны передаться данные. И наоборот.

Пробовал плагины блютуза - не смог сделать.

Есть ли другие варианты: wifi, сервер на одном из устройств?

Буду благодарен за любую информацию

Comment: сервер на Android? o.O

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое и доступное это [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/)

Comment: задача - передача без интернета, то есть с устройства на устройство на прямую